# Text doesn't start at the top in android project layout

Tags: android, layout, textview

I have a Textview in my layout, and I added 4 buttons on the bottom of the page. There is a scrollview added to this, because it is too much to fit in one page. Now after I added the buttons, the text is in the same spot, but starts at the 2nd line. The first line is on top of the screen, not visible. This means that the range is not big enough or something.

But I have a scrollview, so I think it should be possible to just start at the first line and being able to scroll down. Does anyone know how I can fix that? The image down below shows how it looks like. On the top in grey, above the Logo, you can see some other text, which should be in the white part, just with the other text.
Help would be appreciated.

[image]

This is my layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.rodekruis.BWC" >



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rkz_logo" 
        android:layout_gravity="left" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="352dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="405dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_bwc"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />




</ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Facebook" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Youtube" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Twitter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="LinkedIn" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Rodekruis</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_nieuws">NieuwsActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_afspraak">AfspraakActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_bezoek">    Bezoektijden\n\nVrijwel iedere patiënt vindt het prettig bezoek te ontvangen. Onze ervaring is
    dat een goed contact met vrienden en familie een bijdrage kan leveren aan 
    een spoedig herstel.\n\nVoor de meeste afdelingen gelden de volgende bezoektijden:\nvan 15.15 tot 16.15 uur;\nvan 19.00 tot 20.00 uur.\n\nLet op: tijdens feestdagen gelden in het RKZ andere bezoektijden dan normaal.
    Bekijk de website voor uitgebreide bezoektijden.
</string>
    <string name="title_activity_contact">&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Contact&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Telefoon en internet Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis&lt;br /&gt;T 0251 26 5555 (algemeen nummer, ook Poli IJmuiden)&lt;br /&gt;www.rkz.nl<a href='https://www.rkz.nl'> </a>&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Huisartsenpost Midden-Kennemerland (begane grond RKZ)&lt;br /&gt;Voor huisartsenzorg buiten kantooruren&lt;br /&gt;T 0251 26 5265&lt;br /&gt;
    (A.u.b. bellen voordat u langskomt)&lt;br /&gt; Spoedeisende Hulp RKZ en Huisartsenpost: meer informatie&lt;br /&gt;Bij levensbedreigende klachten belt u altijd 112&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Bezoek- en postadres Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis&lt;br /&gt;Vondellaan 13&lt;br /&gt;1942 LE Beverwijk&lt;br /&gt;Route(link)&lt;br /&gt;Postbus 1074&lt;br /&gt;1940 EB Beverwijk
</string>
    <string name="title_activity_mening">MeningActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_route">
        \n\nRoute\n\nRode Kruis Ziekenhuis, hoofdgebouw\nVondellaan 13\n1942 LE Beverwijk\n\nDe Velsertunnel is van medio mei tot eind 2016 gesloten.\nVoor verkeer vanuit zuidelijke richting is het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis in Beverwijk hierdoor moeilijker bereikbaar. Bekijk: \n\n\u2022    actuele verkeersinformatie korte routes naar/van het RKZ\n\u2022    actuele verkeersinformatie langere routers naar/van het RKZ\n\u2022    plan uw route naar/van het RKZ met      actuele verkeersinformatie\n\nRKZ Poli IJmuiden (tijdelijk i.v.m. sluiting Velsertunnel)\nGezondheidscentrum Het Plein\nPlein 1945, nr.1\nIJmuiden\n\u2022    Plan uw route(Google maps)\n\u2022    Meer informatie over de Poli IJmuiden</string>
    <string name="title_activity_specialisten">SpecialistenActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_bwc">
        &lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Het RKZ Brandwondencentrum, beter bekend als: Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk, levert al meer dan veertig jaar topklinische zorg op het gebied van huid-, brandwonden- en littekenbehandelingen en wordt zowel in het binnen- als buitenland hoog gewaardeerd.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Wie werken er in het Brandwondencentrum? Wat maakt het centrum zo bijzonder? Wat is een brandwond precies, wanneer is behandeling in het Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk nodig? Welke behandelingen vinden er plaats? Hoe vindt een opname plaats en wat zijn de bezoekregels? En welke afdelingen en poliklinieken behoren tot het brandwondencentrum?&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Op de website van Brandwondencentrum worden deze vragen uitegebreid beantwoord.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk heeft speciaal voor kinderen en tieners een <a href='https://www.rkz.nl/het_kinderbrandwondencentrum'> </a>
    </string>
    <string name="title_activity_agenda">AgendaActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_info">InfoActivity</string>
    <string name="title_activity_vriend">\n\n\n\nWord vriend van het RKZ\n\n Een verblijf in het ziekenhuis is meestal niet erg plezierig. De Stichting Vrienden van het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis spant zich in om het verblijf van patiënten, bezoekers en medewerkers van het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis en het bijbehorende Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk te veraangenamen. Door geld in te zamelen voor voorzieningen die niet uit het basisbudget van het ziekenhuis kunnen worden betaald. Denk aan een opknapbeurt voor de speelkamer voor jonge patiënten of een verwenbehandeling bij een chemokuur.\n\nOok u kunt helpen. Door Vriend te worden van het RKZ of door ons eenmalig te steunen. Lees verder op de website.\n\nMet vrienden om je heen voel je je beter. Geef om het Rode Kruis Ziekenhuis. 
    </string>
    <string name="title_activity_folders">FoldersActivity</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: can you post your layout code?

Comment: can you put your xml code?

Comment: fyi, usually XML code refers to the layout, not the strings.xml :D

Comment: oh yeah my bad. Well they're both in xD

Comment: Try adding android:fillViewport="true" in your Scrollview in xml.

Comment: change in your string.xml just check it out my answer and let me knw it is working

Comment: I fixed it myself XD in strings.xml, i just added some more enters, aka  &lt;br /&gt; which made it go downwards. It's solved now, thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this  xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
 >



<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:layout_gravity="left" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"/>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="244dp"
    android:layout_height="405dp"

    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/title_activity_bwc"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
 </ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Facebook" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Youtube" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Twitter" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="LinkedIn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

your string.xml:

```
  change your string.xml 


    <string name="title_activity_bwc">
     Het RKZ Brandwondencentrum, beter bekend als: Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk, levert al meer dan veertig jaar topklinische zorg op het gebied van huid-, brandwonden- en littekenbehandelingen en wordt zowel in het binnen- als buitenland hoog gewaardeerd.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Wie werken er in het Brandwondencentrum? Wat maakt het centrum zo bijzonder? Wat is een brandwond precies, wanneer is behandeling in het Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk nodig? Welke behandelingen vinden er plaats? Hoe vindt een opname plaats en wat zijn de bezoekregels? En welke afdelingen en poliklinieken behoren tot het brandwondencentrum?&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Op de website van Brandwondencentrum worden deze vragen uitegebreid beantwoord.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Brandwondencentrum Beverwijk heeft speciaal voor kinderen en tieners een <a href='https://www.rkz.nl/het_kinderbrandwondencentrum'> </a>
</string>
```

Comment: This got it downwards a little bit, but only the very top line is not visible now.. So something is still not 100% right.

Answer (score 0):

Change your ScrollView to,

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
```

Comment: This doesn't fix it. It scrolls down a bit further than usual, but the first coupl e of lines are still not visible

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="405dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_bwc"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Facebook" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Youtube" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Twitter" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button14"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="LinkedIn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Your mistake is that textview height is greater than scrollview size

Comment: So what should i add change? The android:gravity="start" gives me an error, and the height weight sizes on scrollview doesn't change it.

Comment: please check your height of textview and scrollview

Comment: whats is your issue now ?

Comment: your scrollview height is 352 and textview size is 405. make both height equal